# Bag with blue, brown, and white blocks

Tags: set-identification

I have this bag and I don’t know which set it came from. Mostly blue, brown and white blocks. Some green flowers with little lime green cylinder blocks, too.

[image]

Comment: Figured it out — it’s part of a Minecraft set that has another bag #3!

Answer (score 5):

This must be part of [21134: The Waterfall Base](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=21134-1):

[image]

It contains all of the visible items and in the required amounts:

- 27 [White Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Groove and 1 Stud in Center (Jumper)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=87580&colorID=1&in=A)
- 11 [Trans-Dark Blue Slope 45 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3039&colorID=14&in=A)
- 6 [Dark Tan Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Masonry Profile](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98283&colorID=69&in=A)
- 8 [Lime Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b&idColor=34)
- 5 [Bright Green Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Flower Edge (4 Knobs / Petals)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33291&idColor=36)
- 17 [Medium Azure Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Groove and 1 Stud in Center (Jumper)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87580&idColor=156)